# http 405 while login with selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use auto login in to a site using selenium through pyhton but it throws

> http: 405 error "Pardon our Interruption. something about your browser made us think you were a bot"

What can I do to avoid it? I would like to see the execution live to check if the code is working correctly which I can't do if I use it in headless mode. Am I wrong?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


usernameStr = 'bucmi1@yandex.com'
passwordStr = 'pmz4'

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(('https://www.milanuncios.com/mis-anuncios/'))

# fill in username and strike a subsequent button
username = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'email')))
username.send_keys(usernameStr)


# wait for transition then continue to fill items
password = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'contra')))
password.send_keys(passwordStr)
 
signInButton = browser.find_element_by_class_name('submit btnSend')
signInButton.click()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At which line do you see the **http: 405 error **? Do you have a set of demo credentials?

Comment: edited the code with the credentials. The 405 error apears once chrome opens

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why you got an error message as :

```
http: 405 error "Pardon our Interruption. something about your browser made us think you were a bot"
```

But I was able to successfully able to *login* through the credentials you provided with your own code adding some minor tweaks through **chrome.options** in **incognito** mode as follows :

- Code Block :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  usernameStr = 'bucmi1@yandex.com'
  passwordStr = 'pmz4'
  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  options.add_argument('--incognito')
  browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  browser.get(('https://www.milanuncios.com/mis-anuncios/'))
  # fill in username and strike a subsequent button
  username = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'email')))
  username.send_keys(usernameStr)
  # wait for transition then continue to fill items
  password = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'contra')))
  password.send_keys(passwordStr)
  signInButton = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div.btnEnviarFrm>input.submit.btnSend[value^='INICIAR']")
  signInButton.click()
  ```

Browser Snapshot :

[image: you were a bot]

Comment: @Zaico Click on the recapcha once, tell them you are not a bot and try again :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers! The problem had something to do with my default profile folder. Don't know exactly what since there are many files I don't understand. But once I created a new one using `options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\dir\\of\\example\\profile")`
could access without problems.